# SignalR on IIS Not Working

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a simple SignalR app that runs fine when self hosted or hosted in VS2015's IIS.

When I attempt to host it in full IIS I don't get very far. Here's my connect code:

```
public void Connect()
{
    _connection = new HubConnection(ServerUri);

    if (_enableDebugging)  //<== is True for debugging right now
    {
        _connection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
        _connection.TraceWriter = Console.Out;
    }

    _hubProxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy(HUB_NAME);

    _hubProxy.On<string>("EchoMessage", EchoMessage);
    _hubProxy.On<AssayDashboardInfo>("ResultsAdded", ResultsAdded);
    _hubProxy.On<AssayDashboardInfo>("ResultsChanged", ResultsChanged);

    _connection.Error += _connection_Error;
    _connection.StateChanged += _connection_StateChanged;

    try
    {
        _connection.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Error("*** Connection failed", e);
    }
}
```

I get no error messages or exceptions. What I DO get is some output in the Console Window:

23:57:41.8538683 - null - ChangeState(Disconnected, Connecting)
23:57:42.0208850 - null - Disconnected
23:57:42.0208850 - null - Transport.Dispose()
23:57:42.0218851 - null - Closed

Again, with no exception or error info I can only assume that it's not finding the hub. The _connection_StateChanged event is called twice - first with "Connecting" then immediately with "Disconnected." And that's as far as I get.

At this point I'm reaching out to see of anyone know what these messages mean or what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Start() is an async method. You need to await it.

Comment: @Pawel I added await. No change. Same result as before.

Comment: but do you await also the Connect method? You need to make it async all the way. I don;t think the code you showed is not enough to tell exactly where the issue is but I suspect you are not using async correctly and basically the connection is disposed before you even try to use it.

Comment: @Pawel... Well, that got me somewhere. I Awaited the Connect, and now I get a "Not Found" error.

Comment: Hard to tell what it means without seeing your code...

Answer (score 0):

(sorry for the English)

I had the same problem then you. I'm not the one who solve it, praise my colleague.

So basically the error came from the virtual folder on the IIS manager. So you have to pointing directly to the root of your file.

hope that useful.